# return True stop the loop in Python?

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, return

I am still a beginner but does not know why the "return True" in a "for loop" stop the loop after the first pass. If I use something else than "return", everything is fine.

```
def roc_valid(self,cote_x,cote_y):
    from graph_chess import board
    p = board()
    side=(side_x,side_y)

    if side == (0,0):
        for (x,y) in (0,1),(0,2),(0,3):
            print(King.ok_to_move(self,x,y))
            if p.getPiece(x,y)=="" and king.ok_to_move(self,x,y):
                return True
```

Comment: my goal is not to break the loop, but to return True"

Comment: It stops the `for` loop because when the `return` statement is encountered, the function immediately returns, ending the loop.

Comment: Return True from what? That's what it does. It makes roc_valid return True.

Comment: Still learning...:) So I should modify the last "if" to return False". Once roc_valid is False, it is ok to stop the loop in that case. Thanks. Got it

Answer (score 1):

`return` statement is to return a value from a function. So, if you use `return` the control will be transferred to the calling function.

If you want to break out of the loop, you need to use `break` statement.

For example,

```
def tempFunc1():
    i = 1
    return i
    print "leaving tempFunc1"

print tempFunc1()
```

It prints just `1`. It doesnt print `leaving tempFunc1` because, the function has returned to the caller before executing the `print "leaving tempFunc1"` statement.

Comment: my goal is not to break the loop, but to return True"

Comment: @user2984887 The condition is met in the first pass itself. So, its okay to return right?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `yield` statement. A `return` statement stops the function and immediately and returns the value while `yield` statement will return the value and but continues where it left.

```
if side == (0,0):
    for (x,y) in (0,1),(0,2),(0,3):
        print(King.ok_to_move(self,x,y))
        if p.getPiece(x,y)=="" and king.ok_to_move(self,x,y):
            yield True
```

Now use: `list(roc_valid(self,cote_x,cote_y))` to get a list of all returned values or just `next(roc_valid(self,cote_x,cote_y))` to get only the first value.

**Demo:**

```
def func():
    for i in xrange(5):
        if i % 2: 
            yield True
...             
>>> list(func())          #all returned values
[True, True]
>>> next(func())          #Just the first returned value
True
```

Related: [The Python `yield` keyword explained](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/231767/the-python-yield-keyword-explained)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to return True, but still keep looping, you may need a pattern like this. I'm calling the variable `retval` but you can call it anything that makes sense

```
def roc_valid(self,cote_x,cote_y):
    from graph_chess import board
    p = board()
    side=(side_x,side_y)
    retval = False

    if side == (0,0):
        for (x,y) in (0,1),(0,2),(0,3):
            print(King.ok_to_move(self,x,y))
            if p.getPiece(x,y)=="" and king.ok_to_move(self,x,y):
                retval = True

    return retval
```