# How do you return true for a boolean return type if you have a for block to execute

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So i was reading this question [return True stop the loop in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20014251/return-true-stop-the-loop-in-python) but its in python and im in c#

anyways i have a method that looks like this

```c#
public bool HasRequirements(string upgradeName){
        for (int i = 0; i < upgradeRequirements [upgradeName].Length; i++) {
            if (upgradesPurchased [upgradeRequirements [upgradeName] [i]]) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

While coding this I figured that returning true would stop the execution of the for block so then I got to thinking how would you return true for a `boolean` return type when you have a for block to execute?

Comment: definitely it will stop the execution the soul purpose of return statement is to give output so it will stop the whole execution. What you want to do in for loop can you provide some description?

Comment: @Paras see the comment on ded answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comments, another extended function which does only return true if all iterations are true:

```
        public bool HasRequirements(string upgradeName){
            for (int i = 0; i < upgradeRequirements [upgradeName].Length; i++) {
                if (upgradesPurchased [upgradeRequirements [upgradeName] [i]]) {
                    // we skip return true
                    continue;
                } else {
                    // false condition, immed return false
                    return false;
                }
            }
            // we did not met false - so we can return true
            return true;
        }
```

If you want to get 'multiple results' - another possibility is to use the [yield](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/yield) statement. You can find an so post describing it in details here: [What is the yield keyword used for in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39476/what-is-the-yield-keyword-used-for-in-c?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Using yield which does continue returning the values based on the following enumerations. Afterwards the return value could be checked if all are true:

```
        public IEnumerable<bool> HasRequirements(string upgradeName)
        {
            bool returnValue = false;
            for (int i = 0; i < upgradeRequirements[upgradeName].Length; i++)
            {
                if (upgradesPurchased[upgradeRequirements[upgradeName][i]])
                {
                    yield return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    yield return false;
                }
            }
            yield return returnValue;
        }
```

Comment: wouldnt this fall through if same `i = 0` returns true and then `i = 1` returns false and then `i = 2` returns true the `boolean` will return true when it should return false

Comment: It would not stop executing, it would continue. So yes, the returnValue would always change to the latest evaluated expression. If you want to return the first found expression value you should directly return the value which would stop the execution. But why would you want to continue the execution if you already determined your return value?

Comment: so like i have a upgrade that has the required components and all 3 have to be purchased before i am able to buy it so if one component has not been bought then it should return false otherwise if all components are bought then it should return true

Comment: Updated my post : )

Answer (score 1):

"if one component has not been bought then it should return false otherwise if all components are bought then it should return true"

Maybe you need to think revert from where you have been heading:

```
public bool HasRequirements(string upgradeName)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < upgradeRequirements [upgradeName].Length; i++) 
    {
        if (upgradesPurchased [upgradeRequirements [upgradeName] [i]]) 
        {
            continue; 
        } else {
            return false;  // if one component has not been bought
        }
    }
    return true; // all components were bought
}
```

Now if the current purchase being checked is done, then continue to next, basically ignore it and move on. But if one is not done, it is enough to consider the current state faulty so return false and discard anymore checks since it will be false in the end whatsoever.

Comment: The answer is so simple can't believe I didn't get it